# not displaying all the buttons

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have an array with buttons:

```
JButton[] commandButtons = {
    new JButton("Add Chair"),
    new JButton("Add Table"),
    new JButton("Add Desk"),
    new JButton("Clear All"),
    new JButton("Total Price"),
    new JButton("Save"),
    new JButton("Load"),
    new JButton("Summary")
        };
```

I want to put them all in the panel, but it is displaying only the last button.
so if anyone know how to fix it or have an advice it would be great.

Also I am not sure how to do the for loop as a for each.

```
for(int i=0; i<commandButtons.length; i++)      
    {
    westPanel.add(commandButtons[i]);
        commandButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - had you considered using a `JToolBar` for the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Set a FlowLayout manager on the westPanel JPanel and they will all show up.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have not set layout, so the default one is `BorderLayout`. When you are adding elements to this layout without telling the parameter (where to put the element) it is added by default to the center. But there can be only one element in the center, so you see only the last button.

The fast fix is define flow layout:

`pannel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

Do it before adding the buttons. Now you will see all buttons. If you do not see enlarge the window.

Now, if the layout is not what you really want, read about layouts and decide which one (or combination of them) do you need.

Comment: *"you have not set layout, so the default one is BorderLayout."*  Not for a panel.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it depends on the layout manager. If you want no layout manager you have to set the location and size yourself, otherwise they'll all be 0,0.

```
setLayout(null); //gives no layout manager
```

Always try to use a layout manager though.

Comment: technically correct but a no-no-never to do ;-) please don't spread bad and (ultimately) back-firing habits

Comment: I accept that you should always try not to do this, but sometimes the only way to achieve what you're trying to do is to do it this way. Animated movement for example.

Comment: those contexts are extemely rare (and even then a highly specialized LayoutManager might be a better solution, search f.i. for DragLayout :-), this question has not the slightest indication that it might be one of those.